# Symfony2: 1 to M: persisting two objects in same webform

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm getting "The Country should not be blank." message when tying to persist data in two different entities in same form. Any reason why?

**RELATION**: `Country (1) -> (M) League`

**CONTROLLER VER 1**

```
        $submission = $form->getData();
        $countryData = $submission['country'];
        $leagueData = $submission['league'];
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $country = new Country();
        $country->setCode($countryData->getCode());
        $em->persist($country);

        $league = new League();
        $league->setName($leagueData->getName());
        $league->setCountry($country);
        $em->persist($league);

        $em->flush();
```

**CONTROLLER VER 2**

```
        $submission = $form->getData();
        $countryData = $submission['country'];
        $leagueData = $submission['league'];
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $country = new Country();
        $country->setCode($countryData->getCode());

        $league = new League();
        $league->setName($leagueData->getName());
        $league->setCountry($country);

        $em->persist($country);
        $em->persist($league);
        $em->flush();
```

**FORM TYPE**

```
    $builder
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->setAction($options['action'])
        ->add('country', new CountryType())
        ->add('league', new LeagueType())
        ->add('button', 'submit', array('label' => 'Submit'))
        ;
```

**COUNTRY**

```
class Country
{
    protected $id;
    protected $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="League", mappedBy="country", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $league;
}
```

**LEAGUE**

```
class League
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country", inversedBy="league", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="The Country should not be blank.")
     */
    protected $country;
}
```

Comment: The `country` field should be in the `LeagueType` form. You should create a `LeagueType` form class, then include the `country` field there, so they cascade when being inserted on the DB.

Comment: +1. Your hint was the begining of the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Isouza described above, I had to update my `LeagueType` so this is how it started working. The reason why I suffered is because I sometimes use the `LeagueType` on its own as a form or use in one form with others formtypes so I now have to pass a parameters when it is to be used in a combined form. Controller Ver 1 above is prefered.

**When Used on its own:**

```
new LeagueType();
```

**When used in a combined form:**

```
new LeagueType(true);
```

**LeagueType**

```
class LeagueType extends AbstractType
{
    private $cascadeCountry;

    public function __construct($cascadeCountry = false)
    {
        $this->cascadeCountry = $cascadeCountry;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setAction($options['action'])
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Name'))
        ;

        //Used when forms are combined
        if ($this->cascadeCountry === true) {
            $builder
                ->add('country', new CountryType())
            ;
        //Used when the form is used on it own
        } else {
            $builder
                ->add('country', 'entity', array(
                        'label' =>'Country',
                        'class' => 'FootballTeamBundle:Country',
                        'property' => 'name',
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'expanded' => false,
                        'empty_value' => '',
                        'query_builder' =>
                            function (EntityRepository $repo) {
                                return $repo->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
                            }
                    ))
            ;
        }

        $builder
            ->add('button', 'submit', array('label' => 'Submit'))
        ;
    }
}
```